# Meteor - what can and can't be included in the HEAD tag in 2016

Tags: meteor

What can and can't be included in the `head` tag in **Meteor**.

Can I include all the tags in the `head` as usually I do with a static *.html*?

For example:

- `meta`: `viewport, description, keywords, author, charset, http-equiv`
- `link`: `canonical, favicons(icon,apple-touch-icon..), manifest, mask-icon...`
- `open:graph, twitter:cards`

I read that I should not include *GA* `script` and *FB pixel* `script` dirrectly in the `head`. Is it still so in 2016?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29981935/2805154 for a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies if this gets a bit wordy

**short answer**: static app wide meta tags fine, dynamic/per page are not, analytics - no to head unless a one page site

**Meta**

If you have a router and multiple pages you can't include normal meta tags in `<head>` template if you want them to change on a per page basis for SEO bots, which means a definite no to the seo/og/twitter tags on just putting them in the header (unles you are a single page site).

The reason for this being that the head is static on Meteor once it has done the initial page load so would always have the tags you specify. When you define multiple `<head>` tags Meteor will bundle all of them together causing issues for bots visiting your page for things like duplicated og tags. There is no handlebars support for meta tags so you can't set them dynamically.

You CAN use the head for things like the viewport and stuff which is static across all your pages.

You CAN change the page title dynamically but this isn't much good for SEO tags as a bot only usually sees first hit (title not loaded at this point) and then loads a link rather than clicking through the application.

```
onAfterAction: function(){
  document.title = "My pages name";
}
```

**Tracking**

For analytics you can load the scripts in the head but you would want to execute your tracking events from your router. To tae the code from GA Universal Analytics page

```
//GOES IN HEAD
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

//GOES IN ROUTER
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

You may want to use a package to avoid all the complications of setting this up correctly - plenty of them [here](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=analytics) but I couldn't say which ones support fb pixel but most support ga out of the box. I've been using the reywood one and it seems pretty solid

If you are using a mobile app as well remember to set allow rules for all of your tracking domains.

**Workaround for meta**

You need to implement something like spiderable to load a static instance of you page server side to send to bots - this is very useful for the likes of search engines which may penalise you if your page content doesnt match.

If you are more concerned with facebook/twitter being able to scrape without overhead of server creating a static page there is a package which allows you to inject meta data directly into your head on first page load but it is tied to Iron router so not much good if thats not your router... [initial-iron-meta](https://atmospherejs.com/pip87/initial-iron-meta) (disclaimer - I did make this package but it was to solve exactly this issue without having to go mental with server side rendering so I thought I'd throw it out there)

**Flow Router**
If you are using flow-router I think you can use the [kadira:dochead package](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-dochead) to set the meta instead using server side rendering